BB and crankset choice for BSA 68mm BB-shell
I want to replace the square taped BB (together with the crankset) from my old MTB. I am considering hollowtec BB and 2-piece crankset (with single chainring).
The BB Shell width is 68mm.
The old BB is Feimin FP-B902/2S, with thread standards "BC1.37x24T".

For hollowtec BB from Shimano, I notice that both BB-MT501 and BB-RS501 can be installed on my 68mm BSA BB-Shell. I tend to choose RS501 as it matches 68mm shell width, while MT501 matches both 68mm and 73mm width using spacers.
For the 2-piece crankset, I want to choose a single chainring one. But I don't know the compatible models (from Shimano or not, but match the price with BB).
Btw, I already changed the rear hub with IGH (Shimano SG-3D55), which has chainline 42mm or 47mm (depending on the direction the cog is installed, according to the manual). I also want to take the chain alignment into consideration.

I bought the following BB and Crankset from ProWheel, for a first try.


For BB-width consideration: I measured the "supporting distance" on the crank axle, which is 95mm. By "supporting distance" I mean the distance betw the two bearings' outer surface. Also measured the cups's width (11.5mm each), then I decided to add one piece of 2.5mm spacer on each side. After install the cups, the distance betw the outer surface of the cups is about 96mm, a little bit larger than 95mm, which is kind of ok I think.

For Chainline consideration: as the chainline value (47mm) of my IGH hub is a kind of "small", most likely the chainline of the crankset is going to be bigger. So, in the first place, the crankset I choose is the type that the chainring is installed inwards of the crankram, such that if I want to decrease the chainline at the crankset, I have the opportunity to adding spacers; then I choose to add one piece (instead of two, as officially instructed) of 2.5mm spacers on the right side of the BB, to reduce the chainline at the crankset. It turns out that without extra spacers on the chainring, the chain alignment seems ok by eye inspection (although not measured/tested yet).


